# Find Reservation Cross Dates (Checkin, Checkout) Or Same Dates Per Room ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have multiple Reservations in my database. each reservation belong to different apartment. now some reservations are booked twice on the same dates or a little cross on the dates which means it is overbooked How can i make a query that will filter per property and find the overbooked reservations and return me a count of them? I Tried:

```
function getOverbookingcount() {

    $sql = "    
    SELECT *
    FROM reservations a
    INNER JOIN reservations b
    ON DATE(b.start) > DATE(a.start) AND DATE(b.start) < DATE(a.end)
    AND a.room_id != b.room_id
    ";

    $result = return_ci()->db->query($sql);
    return $result->result_array();
}
```

Without any luck.

Table: reservations

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
DBASE_ID | room_id | start              | end
-------------------------------------------------------------
1        |76036    |2015-12-15 14:00:00 | 2015-12-19 11:00:00
2        |76036    |2016-01-17 14:00:00 | 2016-01-19 11:00:00
3        |76036    |2015-10-29 14:00:00 | 2015-11-01 11:00:00
4        |76036    |2015-10-30 14:00:00 | 2015-11-05 11:00:00
5        |103099   |2015-12-15 14:00:00 | 2015-12-19 11:00:00
6        |103099   |2016-01-17 14:00:00 | 2016-01-19 11:00:00
7        |103099   |2015-10-29 14:00:00 | 2015-11-01 11:00:00
8        |103099   |2015-10-29 14:00:00 | 2015-11-03 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT r1.DBASE_ID, r1.room_id, r1.start, r1.end
FROM reservations AS r1
INNER JOIN reservations AS r2 
  ON r1.room_id = r2.room_id AND
     r1.DBASE_ID < r2.DBASE_ID AND
     r1.start <= r2.end and r1.end >= r2.start
```

These conditions:

```
     r1.start <= r2.end and r1.end >= r2.start
```

check for *overlapping* intervals between two different reservation records.

In case of an overlap between two reservations records, the above query returns the record having the *smallest* `DBASE_ID` value. To return *both* records you should use: `r1.DBASE_ID <> r2.DBASE_ID` instead of: `r1.DBASE_ID < r2.DBASE_ID`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31750/1)

Comment: It seems to be doing something, returned me 10 results. for some reason it shows me the same reservation 3 times.. why could it happen?

Comment: In this case the same reservation overlaps with 3 different reservation records. You can do a `SELECT DISTINCT` if you want to avoid duplicates.